# error while creating table using Yii2 migration

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm pretty new to `yii2`, I'm using **postgres**, my `db.php` file is -

```
return [
       'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
       'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=xxxx',
       'username' => 'postgres',
       'password' => 'abc',
       'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

I have create one table directly in postgres and fetched the data successfully using `ActiveRecord`.
Then I went for creating a table using migration with

```
./yii migrate/create logins
```

which successfully created a file in migration folder, then i put following content in `up` method -

```
public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('logins', [
            'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
            'name' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
            'password' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL'
    ]);
}
```

and fired `./yii migrate` to update a database, but I'm getting following error -

```
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.10)
Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver'
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/server/api/project/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:549
```

Is there any step I'm missing? or there is some problem in postgres connection?

Comment: Have you got `db` component configured in your console application?

Comment: no I haven't, can you tell me how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is basic template.

Make sure you have got `db` component configured.

In your `config/console.php` file check if there is `db` key in `components` section like:

```
// ...
'components' => [
    // ...
    'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    // ...
],
```

If everything is ok with it but error is still present you need to check if you have got `pgsql` driver properly installed.

See [PDO Installation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php) for details.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes there is already a component section like this

Comment: So check if driver is installed, see my answer updated.